# My script is not retrieving an item for a list. I would appreciate it, if someone could help me understand why?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am required to change the xkcd project in the AtBS book to download the comics from a different website. Here is my script.

```
#! python3
# getwebcomic.py - Downloads every single smbc comic.

import requests, os, bs4

os.chdir('C:\\Users\\Bob\\Desktop\\')
url = 'https://smbc-comics.com' # starting url
os.makedirs('smbc', exist_ok=True) # store comics in ./smbc
noAbuse=0

for noAbuse in range(0, 5):
#while not url.endswith('#'):
    # Download the page.
    print('Downloading page %s...' % url)
    res = requests.get(url)
    res.raise_for_status()

    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")

    # Find the URL of the comic image.
    comicElem = soup.select('#cc-comicbody')
    print('I am finding it')
    print(comicElem)
    if comicElem == []:
        print('Could not find comic image.')
    else:
        print(comicElem[0].get('src'))
        print('I dont know why the .get is returning NONE!')
        print('It is there???')
        print('...and now it crashes')
        comicUrl = 'https//smbc-comics.com' + comicElem[0].get('src')
        print(comicUrl)
        # Download the image.

        print('Downloading image %s...' % (comicUrl))
        res = requests.get(comicUrl)
        res.raise_for_status()

        # Save the image to ./smbc
        imageFile = open(os.path.join('smbc', os.path.basename(comicUrl)), 
'wb')
       for chunk in res.iter_content(100000):
            imageFile.write(chunk)
        imageFile.close()

    # Get the Prev button's url.
   prevLink = soup.select('a[rel="prev"]')[0]
   url = 'http://smbc-comic.com' + prevLink.get('href')

print('Done.')
```

***OutPut***

```
Downloading page https://smbc-comics.com...

I am finding it
[<div id="cc-comicbody"><img border="0" id="cc-comic" 
 src="/comics/1524150658-20170419 (1).png" 
 title="You can also just use an infinite quantity of compasses as on-off switches."/><br/></div>]
None
```

I dont know why the `.get` is returning NONE!
It is there???
...and now it crashes

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\Bob\PythonScripts\getwebcomic.py", line 31, in <module>
>       comicUrl = 'https//smbc-comics.com' + comicElem[0].get('src')
>   TypeError: must be str, not NoneType

I can't seem to figure out why the .get method is returning none when the 'src' attribute is there. Any hints would be appreciated. I put in some extra print() to help me see what is happening when the script runs.

Comment: Are you familiar with Python debugger?  You could use it to interact with `comicElem` object to see what it contains and what type and attributes `comicElem[0]` actually has.

Comment: I got it to work. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

`comicElem[0]` is a division (`<div>`). It does not have an `src` attribute, and that is why `.get` returns `None`. You should try `comicElem[0].img.get("src")` instead, which returns `"/comics/1524150658-20170419 (1).png"`.